# Upcalling with singledispatch

Tags: python, super

I'm curious if it's possible to emulate the normal invocation of `super().method()` for calling the "parent's" `method()`, but using `singledispatch` instead of method polymorphism.

So far as I can tell, the answer is "no". I don't think indexing into the MRO is a viable solution, but could be wrong.

```
from functools import singledispatch

class A:
  pass

class B(A):
  pass

@singledispatch
def f(obj):
    raise NotImplementedError(obj)

@f.register(A)
def _(obj):
  print('A')

@f.register(B)
def _(obj):
  print('B')
  f.dispatch(super(B, obj))

b = B()
# I want this to print "B" then "A"
f(b)
```

Output

```
B
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 29, in <module>
    f(b)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/functools.py", line 840, in wrapper
    return dispatch(args[0].__class__)(*args, **kw)
  File "main.py", line 24, in _
    f.dispatch(super(B, obj))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/functools.py", line 795, in dispatch
    impl = dispatch_cache[cls]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/weakref.py", line 396, in __getitem__
    return self.data[ref(key)]
TypeError: cannot create weak reference to 'super' object
```

Comment: `f.dispatch(A)(b)`

Comment: I want to use the MRO linearization logic to select the right invocation. Just as I would normally use `super().f()`instead of calling `A.f(self)` directly.

Comment: Then you have no choice but to index into the MRO.